# use managed compatibility mode option not available in Visual studio 2012

Tags: c#, debugging, visual-studio-2012, visual-studio-debugging

I am trying to debug my application but i get weard behavior when i am hovering over the variable during runtime.
I am not able to see the values of variables on hovering if the variable is a property with getter and setter.

I think enabling use managed compatibility mode option could solve this problem, but this option is not available in Debugging -> general. 
where can i find this option in Visual studio 2012?

Comment: It's there, it had a different name in 2012.  Can't remember anymore, press F1.

Comment: @HansPassant Did not find anything in help

Comment: IIRC, the setting that is *not* described in the help is the one you are looking for :)

Comment: Compatibility mode is obviously the legacy mode. Latter versions of Visual Studio add new engine that support new features but in some cases the new engine might not work properly so in those case, the compatibility mode would  essentially give you VS 2012 behavior. as bugs and limitations are fixed in new engine, there are less and less reason to use old engine if you debug in current Visual Studio version with all update applied.

Answer (score 1):

It is a new option from VS2013, it has no that option in the VS2012. But it has the option "Managed C++ compatibility mode" in VS2012 if you installed the update 5.

https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/visualstudioalm/2013/10/16/switching-to-managed-compatibility-mode-in-visual-studio-2013/

In old VS version, C# and VB projects do not have a way to turn off managed debugging.

The option "Enable native code debugging" in the C# project properties means in mixed debugging.

The option "Managed Compatibility Mode" was used to managed and mixed debugging but not to native-only debugging.